# Detecting memory leaks in MFC application

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc

I'm writing an MFC app using Visual 2017 and when the application exits in debug mode, I get this:

> Detected memory leaks! Dumping objects -> {74} normal block at
>   0x00000230E49A7000, 16 bytes long.  Data: <0   0           > 30 00 97
>   E4 30 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Object dump complete.

So, in order to know which function is causing the leak, I've added these lines in stdafx.h:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

And these lines in CWinApp::InitInstance():

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
_CrtSetBreakAlloc(74);
```

Though, it did not work. I suspect that the 74th memory allocation number has been made before my code is executed. Which method could I overload to be certain to be called first?

Comment: Is it always 74?

Comment: Yes, it's always 74. I found out that the memory leak happened in a non-MFC code I imported into my project. Though, I guess _CrtSetDbgFlag is not called before this code executes.

Comment: I put these lines in the constructor of the main class of the external code, and the debugger stops when allocating a std::vector on the stack (not on the heap). Very strange...

Comment: ***std::vector on the stack*** Remember the vector may be on the stack but it allocates from the heap.

Comment: Perhaps the leak report is a false positive.

Comment: It was a class member of this kind: std::vector<char> so I don't think it can trigger a memory leak... Anyway, where do you usually put _CrtSetDbgFlag in a MFC app?

Comment: Is the class a singeleton?

Comment: Well, it's not technically a singleton but it is instantiated only once, if that was your question.

Answer (score 3):

Step into your app to start debugging (that's step, not run, so you'll be stopped in the debugger before anything in your program has run), then set `_crtBreakAlloc` to the allocation you want to stop at (74).  Then run and you should get a break on the 74th allocation.  [CRT Debug Heap Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx#BKMK_Track_Heap_Allocation_Requests) has information on this variable.

[This Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/151585/how-to-use-crtbreakalloc-to-debug-a-memory-allocation) also lists instructions for using `_crtBreakAlloc` in the debugger.

Comment: I did that but the debugger didn't break before the end of the program. But I'm wondering something: since I called _CrtSetDbgFlag in the CWinApp::InitInstance(), the heap instrumentation has been activated too late, don't you think?

Comment: @MarkMorrisson Correct.  Either the 74th allocation has already occurred when you call _CrtSetBreakAlloc, or your program never gets to that 74th allocation.

Comment: So, what can I do?

Comment: Please add instructions for calling _CrtSetBreakAlloc(74); when at a breakpoint. I tried the Immediate window, but it said `identifier "_CrtSetBreakAlloc" is undefined`.

Comment: @ScottHutchinson You use the `_CrtSetBreakAlloc` function to set a break count in your code.  In the debugger, set the `_crtBreakAlloc` global variable.

Comment: Thanks. I found these instructions for how to do it using the Watch window: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/151585/how-to-use-crtbreakalloc-to-debug-a-memory-allocation

Comment: @ScottHutchinson I've updated my answer to include your useful support article link.

Comment: Sadly, I still cannot make it work: Whatever I type in the Watch window, I just get a message like "  {,,msvcr40d.dll}*__p__crtBreakAlloc() Module "msvcr40d.dll" not found. 
Even when I type {,,msvcr110d.dll}*__p__crtBreakAlloc() even though I can see that dll file in the debug folder, I still get Module "msvcr110d.dll" not found.

Comment: I am debugging a Multi-Threaded Debug DLL (/MDd), but I get this for step 1a: _crtBreakAlloc identifier "_crtBreakAlloc" is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Writing this code

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

in top of each implementation (.CPP) file, can help you to detect the source of memory leaks.
See also: [How to detect memory leaks in MFC](http://codexpert.ro/blog/2012/12/25/how-to-detect-memory-leaks-in-mfc/).

Comment: Since I'm including in my project many external files, I added these lines at the end of stdafx.h (which is normally included by every source file) but it didn't work better.

Comment: You cannot add the `#define new DEBUG_NEW` to the bottom of the `stdafx.h` file. It must be in each `.cpp` file.